# Как из первого активити изменить цвет фона второго активити?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, color, android-constraintlayout

```
ConstraintLayout lay = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    Switch darktema = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.darktema);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
    if (darktema.isChecked()) {
        int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dark);
        lay.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }else{
        int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.thiscolor);
        lay.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
```

этот код изменяет цвет оновного активити. Как изменить и цвет второго активити тоже? Если что id его ConstraintLayout - "add".

Comment: В вопросе вам следует указать, что по факту вам нужно не изменить цвет другого активити, а применять темы к своему приложению. Дело в том, что андроид имеет вполне вменяемые инструменты работы с темами, а не какие о костыльные переключения фонов, которые вы пытаетесь использовать. Соответственно и ответ на ваш вопрос будет другой

Comment: @pavlofff Напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее про эти инструменты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете отправить значение переменной `backgroundColor` через `Intent`.

Примерный код в первой `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
if (darktema.isChecked()) {
    int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dark);
    lay.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    intent.putExtra("backgroundColor", backgroundColor);
} else {
    int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.thiscolor);
    lay.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    intent.putExtra("backgroundColor", backgroundColor);
};
startActivity(intent);
```

Примерный код в `AddActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    View yourRootView = findViewById(R.id.your_root_view);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int backgroundColor = intent.getInt("backgroundColor");
    yourRootView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
};
```

**UPDATE**

Если `AddActivity` уже создано, то изменить тему в нём можно, например, с помощью [`Singleton`](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0).

Примерный `Singleton`:

```
class YourSingletonClass {

    Context addActivityContext = null;

    private YourSingletonClass () {
    };

    protected class Instance {
        private final static YourSingletonClass instance = new YourSingletonClass();
    };

    public static YourSingletonClass getInstance() {
        return Instance.instance;
    };

    public void setAddActivityContext(Context addActivityContext) {
        this.addActivityContext = addActivityContext;
    };

    public Context getAddActivityContext() {
        return this.addActivityContext;
    };
}
```

Тогда в `AddActivity`:

```
YourSingletonClass.getInstance().setAddActivityContext(AddActivity.this);
```

Соответственно, из первой `Activity` после этого можно будет изменить фон так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
if (darktema.isChecked()) {
    int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dark);
    lay.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
} else {
    int backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.thiscolor);
    lay.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
};
((AddActivity) YourSingletonClass.getInstance().getAddActivityContext()).yourRootView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
```

`yourRootView` должен быть объявлен вне методов .

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтоб было без startActivity. Я делаю темную тему, и нужно чтобы второе активити не вызывалось, но меняло цвет

Comment: @edcft, конечно, мой код не самый простой, но он должен работать

Comment: вообще то, если человек делает темы, то андроид имеет инструменты работы именно с темами, а не вот это вот все ..

Answer (score 0):

Используя интент можно передать информацию о темной теме. При переходе на другую активность передаете данные:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("dark", darktema.isChecked());
startActivity(intent);
```

и в второй активности обработать приходящие данные:

```
intent.getBooleanExtra("dark", false);
```

так же ваш код можно немного улучшить:

```
lay.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,if (darktema.isChecked()) {
R.color.dark
}else{
R.color.thiscolor
}));
```

я думаю так будет красивее :) В активности  `AddActivity.class` можно сделать такую обработку данных о темной теме:

```
int color = if(ContextCompat.getColor(this,intent.getBooleanExtra("sample", false){
R.color.dark
}else{
R.color.thiscolor
}));
```